# Jquery Validation with Master Page, html controls validation being ignored

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

Jquery Validation seems to ignore the validation part for some reason I am not sure. I am using asp.net master page with pure html controls and knockout binding I have removed code to make it more readable.  What should I do to get the validation to fire.

**Master Page code**

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
   <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>


  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">

  </form>
</body>
```

**Content Page and Jquery Plugin**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
       var istrue= $('#aspForm').validate(
       {
                rules: {
                    name:
                            {
                                required: true
                            }
                },
                messages: {
                    name:
                                {
                                    required: "Please enter a name"
                                }
                }
            });


    });

    // **All view models are declare removed** 
    self.SearchNext = function () {
      if ($('#aspForm').valid()) { //<== **always shows true**

      }
    }
   </script>

    ....
    ....
    ....
  <div align="center">
        <button type="button" id="btnNext" class="submitButton" data-bind="click:SearchNext">  //<== I am using knockout binding here
            Next</button>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Error shown**

Chrome console shows this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
```

**Update 1**

I have this line in the content page

But not in the master page would that be part of the problem

Comment: Is there a form on the page with an id of `aspForm`?

Comment: no there is one like this in the master page <form id="form1" runat="server">. I tried to change it to form1 too

Comment: if I try with form1 $('#form1').validate(...) always is true